# What does "to coordinate candidates" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a part of an article from Wikipedia about political parties:

A political party is an organization that **coordinates** candidates to compete in a particular country's elections.

What does it mean to coordinate candidates?

Cambridge dic def for coordinate
to organize all the different activities and people who are involved in something so that it works effectively:

Comment: Not the best choice of verb there. A political party is an organization that **presents or selects** candidates.....

Comment: That seems like a useful definition of *coordinate* (and at least part of a party's work, even if not all of it). Please edit the question to explain more about how this definition doesn't solve your concerns.

Comment: It's worth remembering that Wikipedia's articles are submitted by volunteers. I once corrected a dozen clear grammatical mistakes in an article, only to find that the author had changed all my corrections back to the original prose.

Comment: "*Cambridge dic def for coordinate to organize all the different activities* …" needs to be written much more clearly. There is no need to use abbreviations such as "dic" and "def" that will probably confuse other learners of English. Text speech is fine when there is a lack of space or time but on ELL those constraints are not present.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you provided for *coordinate* can help us understand what it means in the context of this sentence.

Sentence in question:

> A political party is an organization that *coordinates* candidates to compete in a particular country's elections.

Applying the definition of coordinate:

> A political party is an organization that *organizes the **candidates** who are involved in **a particular country's elections** so that **the election** works effectively*.